# Python printing out PHP code

Tags: php, python

Just out of curiosity, I know it's possible having a HTML web page fully printed out in Python, such as:

```
print 'Content-type: html\n\n'
print '<html>'
print '<head><title>My first Python CGI app</title></head>'
print '<body>'
print '<p>Hello, world!</p>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Is it also possible to do something similiar with PHP?

Comment: have you tried to do it? did it work?

Comment: change `print` to `echo`?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp

Comment: You're title suggests that you want Python to output PHP-code?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That is correct.

Comment: I have to ask... Why? Anyway, you can, but the PHP-code won't get executed. Python will print the PHP-code as literal strings and send it to the browser. The browser will just output it to the screen. PHP needs to be executed on the server before anything get sent to the browser. I guess that you theoretically _COULD_ do it if you sent the output through PHP-parser (in your Python script) before you send it to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
print """
<?php
   $wtfs = array("what", "the", "freak", "is", "this", "shnitz");
   echo "<ul>\n";
   foreach($wtfs as $wtf) {
       echo "<li>$wtf</li>\n";
   }
   echo "<li>???</li>\n";
   echo "</ul>\n";
?>
"""
```